# Questions related to Colon Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> If $A= \mathbb{F}[x]$ and $I=(x^2)$ and $S=\{x\}$ then find $I: S$.

Attempt: $I:S=\{p \in \mathbb{F}[x]\mid pS\subseteq I\}$ then $px\in (x^2)$ and $px=c_0x^2 +c_1x^2+\cdots (c_i \in \mathbb{F})$, then $p =I:S$  will be equal to $(x)$.

Is it fine?

> If $A =\mathbb{F}[x,y]$ , $I=(x^2y,xy^2)$, $S=\{y^2\}$, then what will be $I:S$?

$I:S$ here will be equal to $\{p\in\mathbb{F}[x,y] \mid p S\subseteq I\}$ which means that $py^2= c_0 x^2y + c_1 xy^2 + c_2 x^2 y +c_1 xy^2+\cdots$.

I am unable to find by hit and trial in this case and I think I need help.

Comment: $pS\in I$ makes no sense. $S$ is a set, so $pS$ is a set; it should be $pS\subseteq I$ or $px\in I$ for all $x\in S$.

Comment: "$px=c_0x^2+c_1x^2+\cdots$, $c_i\in\mathbb{F}[x,y]$" is incorrect as written. You aren't even working in $\mathbb{F}[x,y]$. Your argument at best shows one inclusion (and that is arguable), not equality. Simply: if $px\in (x^2)$, then $x^2$ divides $xp$, hence $x$ divides $p$, hence $p\in (x)$. Thus $I:S\subseteq (x)$. Conversely, if $p\in (x)$, then $x^2$ divides $xp$, so $xp\in (x^2)$. Thus, $(x)\subseteq I:S$, giving equality.

Comment: The second problem is likewise nonsensical as written: if the ring is $\mathbb{F}[x]$, then $I=(x^2y,xy^2)$ is not even a subset of $A$, so what are you doing and where are you working?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ya man . sorry

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have edited it. It was written badly.  Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write $py^2=x^2yf+xy^2g$ with $f,g\in F[x,y]$. Then $y^2\mid x^2 yf$, that is, $y\mid x^2f$ which implies $y\mid f$. Now write $f=yf_1$ and get  $py^2=x^2y^2f_1+xy^2g$, so  $p=x^2f_1+xg$ which shows us that $p\in(x)$. I leave you the pleasure to show the converse.

Comment: Is answer of 1st question fine?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.